# Can we make changes to Australian visitor visa application after submitting the file?

Tags: visas, australia

In particular, I want to arrive earlier than planned. I am a student and wanted to go see my sister. The main reason was her graduation ceremony. However, since the preparation for the file got late from our side, we changed the reason to normal meet up because we haven't met for a long time. But my uncle told me the chances of visa are much less now as the reason for the meeting is not very strong. Are there any chances I can change the reason and my arrival dates?

Comment: Don't listen to your uncle.  Changing the stated reason is just going to raise a red flag and make them look more closely at your application.

Answer (score 3):

Application instructions can be found on the immigration website:

[Online applications](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/applying-online-or-on-paper/online)

[Paper applications](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/applying-online-or-on-paper/on-paper)

The relevant section on each is 'Tell us if you made a mistake'

Online:

> To tell us:
>   1. log in to ImmiAccount
>   2. select the check box for the application
>   3. select 'Update details'
>   4. select 'Notification of incorrect answer(s)'
>   5. select 'Add'
>   6. complete the fields
>   7. select 'Confirm'

Paper:

> You can tell us of mistakes on your submitted visa application by:
>   - [checking if you can import your application](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/help-support/applying-online-or-on-paper/online#content-index-14) to update us online, or
>   - use [Form 1023 Notification of Incorrect Answer/s (168KB PDF)](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/929.pdf) and email it to the area that processed your application

That said, I don't think mentioning the graduation will make much of a difference to the strength of the application. They'll probably be more concerned with the evidence that you are a genuine temporary entrant and will comply with the terms of the visa if granted.